# I need a few thousands of threads, should I separate them into different processes? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, websocket

In my code I have a few thousands of client Websocket connections. I put one connection in one thread + some http requests(inner logic) No hard calculations. Is separation of threads better? Like 3 processes, 1k threads each?

I have not tried yet running all the threads in main process.

I just want to compare two situations.

```
main process -> 3000 threads

or
                process -> 1000 threads
main process -> process -> 1000 threads
                process -> 1000 threads
```

Comment: Please provide your code for minimum reproducable example:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: So what you're asking is: is there a practical limit to the number of threads in a single process?

Comment: @MarkRansom, is it more effeciently to allocate threads between processes or it is the same, as keeping all the threads inside one process. Taking into account that I need a few thousandsd of them.

Comment: Keeping thousands of threads/processes won't end well. You will waste lots of cpu time on context switch. And you will waste memory in case of processes. Consider switching two some async framework. You don't need more threads than the number of cores or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually spreading the threads will lead to better results. Although GIL does not apply much to networking, on this scale it might make a big difference.

Keep in mind that your problem is akin to the [10k connections issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem). The "best approach" to solve it is by multiplexing on a single thread, using library such as [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html). Threads have a large overhead, and 3k is far too many for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

A thousand processes would grind any regular PC to a halt. But having a number of processes in the same order of magnitude as the number of cores on your machine may make sense, depending on the work you're doing.

If the tasks rely on some bottlenecked resource, it doesn't really help to parallelise the work. On the other hand, if the tasks have to wait for some asynchronous resource, it may even help to have a few more processes. If the work relies very much on asynchronous resources, focusing on async before multiprocessing may be more worthwhile and you can decide if parallel processing is worth adding later.

In other words: it depends. There is no simple answer that will be true for all situations. You need to be specific about the specific type of problem you're trying to solve and decide what resource is most constraining the work and improve on dealing with that. Multiprocessing can be both a good and a bad thing, depending on circumstances.

If the work you're doing is constrained by the amount of actual computing (on the CPU) your code needs to do, and the work can be parallelised, multiprocessing is likely to help up to the point where all the available cores are hard at work.

In the comments you ask "is it more [efficient] to allocate threads between processes or it is the same, as keeping all the threads inside one process". It's more efficient to allocate work to multiple processes if a.) the work can be done in parallel, b.) there's enough of the work to offset the added overhead of starting the process and passing around the work, and c.) the work mostly depends on how fast the CPU can do its job.

In that case, getting all the cores to work on your task instead of just one will help.

Comment: OP said mostly http, no hard calculations. CPU is just a constraint for processing the requests, which will be loaded when you have 3k concurrent websockets. It's actually more of a clear and cut case I believe (again, according to presentation).

Comment: Yes, I don't disagree and the work is limited to that, your answer contains good advice and deserves the check. I just wanted to add an answer that steers clear of "do this" and instead explain "why do one thing or the other".